# units for kube_metrics_server_pods_cpu metric in prometheus

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, amazon-eks

Can anyone guide if we monitoring out `EKS` cluster using `prometheus`

Then what would be the units for the metric `kube_metrics_server_pods_cpu` by default.

Comment: from looking at the exporter code it looks like it would return the cpu usage for the pod with following labels `labels={ 'pod_name': pod_name, 'pod_namespace': pod_namespace, 'pod_container_name': pod_container_name }` and by past expirience its probably `vCPU cores`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CPU  is measured in nanocores.

`kube_metrics_server_pods_cpu` is measured in nanocores.

I agree with @noam-yizraeli

As per the [source code](https://github.com/olxbr/metrics-server-exporter/blob/bdf831c4e9d794e2f760edf217cf923a7c461d21/app.py#L130) of the [metrics-server-exporter](https://github.com/olxbr/metrics-server-exporter), there is `pod_container_cpu` variable.

```
metrics_pods_cpu.add_sample('kube_metrics_server_pods_cpu', value=int(pod_container_cpu), labels={ 'pod_name': pod_name, 'pod_namespace': pod_namespace, 'pod_container_name': pod_container_name })
```

`pod_container_cpu` is declared [here](https://github.com/olxbr/metrics-server-exporter/blob/bdf831c4e9d794e2f760edf217cf923a7c461d21/app.py#L123)

And [README.md](https://github.com/olxbr/metrics-server-exporter/blob/bdf831c4e9d794e2f760edf217cf923a7c461d21/README.md) says:

> kube_metrics_server_nodes_cpu
>
> - Provides nodes CPU information in nanocores.

## Memory is measured in kibibites.

As for the memory usage, [the same README.md says](https://github.com/olxbr/metrics-server-exporter/blob/master/README.md):

> `kube_metrics_server_nodes_mem`
>
> - Provides nodes memory information in kibibytes.

Comment: Thanks for information. Do u have idea in what units is the pod memory captured?  kube_metrics_server_pods_mem in prometheus

Comment: I've answered: in kibibites